# Java to send command to ftp client using apache commons

Tags: java, ftp

I need to get the date from a server using ftp. I saw this piece of code and was hopeful it will work:

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPCmd;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;

FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

ftpClient.connect(host);

boolean login = ftpClient.login(user, pass);

if (login) {
    int replyCode = ftpClient.sendCommand(FTPCmd.GET_MOD_TIME, "date");

    if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode)) {
        System.out.println("The operation did not succeed!");
    } else {
        System.out.println(ftpClient.getReplyString());
    }
}
```

But running this I get a negative response:

> "The operation did not succeed!"

Comment: can you provide the variable replycode value?

Comment: I'm not familiar with GET_MOD_TIME, does sendCommand(FTPCmd.PWD); return a valid reply?

Comment: Sending .PWD gives a reply code of "/". :)

Comment: I want a return value of the date of the server something like: Fri Jan  9 11:59:36 MYT 2015
Same as when you type date in the cmd line.

Comment: variable replycode value is 530 for "The operation did not succeed!"

Comment: Different ftp sites support different grammars. My guess is that GET_MOD_TIME correlates to the modtime ftp command which would give you the mod time of a specific file. Since you're passing "date" if there wasn't a file called date you would expect to get your did not succeeed message. Since PWD worked at least you know the connection and your authentication worked. None of the ftp servers I looked at had a date command unless I used a shell, ie "$ date" at the ftp prompt. I don't see a way to execute shell commands using FTPClient, but maybe someone else knows how to.